# Triggering more than one jQuery toggle with radio buttons

Tags: jquery, radio-button, toggle

I've managed to figure out how to show a div when a user clicks on a radio button.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6Lwfc/

The problem is that if I have more than one of these quizzes on a page, clicking a radio button will trigger all of them to show their answers.

I've tried changing the classes (e.g. selfTestAnswer2, selfTestAnswer3) to separate them, but it doesn't help. My guess is because clicking a radio button is the same for all of them.

How can I separate these so I can put 2 or 3 on a page?

Comment: Just a little tip... doing this like you're doing makes it super easy to figure out which is the right answer by viewing the source on your page.

Comment: That's ok, it doesn't matter. Client originally didn't even want the answer hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another example using id's on the parent element. http://jsfiddle.net/sailorob/wHULM/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Lwfc/4/

```
$('.selfTestWrong', $(this).parent()).addClass('answerShown');
$('.selfTestAnswer', $(this).parent()).slideDown(300);
```

You needed a context. Also, I removed your dupe ID tags. Never duplicate ID's on a page.